# How to get an Erlang app to run at starting rebar3

Tags: rebar3

I can start the application manually from the rebar3 shell by doing `application:start(lager)` followed by `application:start(myapp)`.  I'd like this to happen without having to type it out, for example by executing a shell script that tells rebar3 to run those commands.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that you want to run the application during development you can do it like this:

- either you specify the apps at commandline like this: `rebar3 shell --apps lager myapp`
- or you specify in rebar.config `{shell, [{apps, [lager, myapp]}]}.` and then simply run it with `rebar3 shell`. For example I have an application named `tron` and have the following line in my rebar.config: `{shell, [{apps, [kernel,stdlib,cowboy,lager,tron]}]}`. Now  when I run `rebar3 shell` my erlang application is started together with all dependencies.

For more information about rebar3 shell and how you can use it, see [this](http://ferd.ca/rebar3-shell.html) awesome blogpost from the creator, or the official documentation [here](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/commands).

But as you probably know, the proper way to run the application for deployment is to first build a **release** and then simply run it as an executable (It was a while since I built a release but back then it was harder than it sounds, unfortunately! Although it looks like rebar3 have perhaps made it abit easier: [rebar3 releases](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases).

Comment: thanks for the good answer - it was surprisingly difficult to get an answer to this seemingly simple question.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to add, that you can also specify apps to be booted on startup inside the myapp.app.src file.

```
...
{applications,
   [kernel,
    stdlib,
    anotherapp
   ]},
...
```

Comment: `$ rebar3 shell` doesn't start the apps listed in the `applications` tuple when I try it--even though the [rebar3 docs](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/dependencies) seem to say that that is the way to start dependent apps. :(